# DateTime Difference - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the DateTime difference between two DateTime values.

Query I have so far,

```
DECLARE @start datetime = '2012-01-01 12:00:00.000'
DECLARE @end datetime =  '2013-01-01 11:59:59.999'

SELECT 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEDIFF(YYYY, @start, @end))
+'-'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEDIFF(MONTH, @start, @end))
+'-'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEDIFF(SECOND, @start, @end)/86400)
+' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEDIFF(SECOND, @start, @end)%86400/3600)
+':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEDIFF(SECOND, @start, @end)%3600/60)
+':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @start, @end)%60)) 
+'.'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @start, @end)%100))
AS [YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MSS]
```

Desired Output

```
0001-00-00 23:59:59.999
365 Days, 23 Hours, 59 Minutes, 59 Seconds, 999 Milliseconds
```

Actual Output

```
1-12-366 8784:0:0.0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)** accuracy is rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds. For better accuracy use **DateTime2** datatype.

```
DECLARE @start datetime2 = '2012-01-01 12:00:00.000'
DECLARE @end datetime2 =  '2013-01-01 11:59:59.999'

--I do this way because millisecond difference overflows the integer.
select datediff(day, @start, @end) days,
       datediff(millisecond, convert(time, @start), convert(time, @end)) milliseconds
```

Results and **[fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22943)**:

```
   days | milliseconds
   366  | -1
```

Above results means you can get desired results:

```
  (366 days - 1 millisecond) =  
   365 Days, 23 Hours, 59 Minutes, 59 Seconds, 999 Milliseconds
```

**EDIT:** Please note that millisecond difference between given two dates are too high and in fact overflowing bigint as well. So I use **[THIS APPROACH](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/23072)**  to get your expected answer.

Comment: Does that work?  With those values, convert(@endtime) for me is returning 12:00:00.0000000.

Comment: @Andrew, please note I am using `DATETIME2` datatype. (i.e. `DECLARE @end DATETIME2` ) it will give you `11:59:59.999`.

Comment: Yeah, just caught that. /bonk

Comment: This technique works. Would you happen to know if 1st desired format is possible? If so, how? Edit: THANK YOU!!! Edit # 2: TIL the practical diff between DATETIME and DATETIME2.

Comment: Yes, I knew DateTime type was not accurate to 1ms. You are welcome !

Comment: sry, but I am getting 1999 and -999 and etc if I flip/change the milliseconds for start and end time. Can you show me how you got "(366 days - 1 millisecond) =  
   365 Days, 23 Hours, 59 Minutes, 59 Seconds, 999 Milliseconds" part?

Comment: Given you an example. Please check the edit notes. Enjoy it is Friday !!

Comment: Thanks Kaf!!!, I was trying http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/9472 but it's not as accurate as yours. ThX

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the Start and End, it seems like SQL Server was rounding it when it was .999.

```
DECLARE @start datetime = '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @end datetime =  '2013-01-01 23:59:59.997'

SELECT 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEDIFF(YYYY, @start, @end))
+'-'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEPART(mm, @Start) - DATEPART(mm, @End))
+'-'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEPART(dd, @Start) - DATEPART(mm, @End))
+' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEPART(hh, @Start) - DATEPART(hh, @End))
+':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEPART(mi, @Start) - DATEPART(mi, @End))
+':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEPART(ss, @Start) - DATEPART(ss, @End))
+'.'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEPART(ms, @Start) - DATEPART(ms, @End))
AS [YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MSS]
```

Comment: start = '2012-01-01 12:00:00.000'
end =  '2012-01-02 12:59:59.997'
with above values, shouldn't the output be 0-0-1 0:59:59.997?